# How to change time zone on iPod touch 4?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod, timezone

How can I change the time zone on my iPod touch?  Presently it shows Eastern time zone, but I am on the west coast for a bit and it still shows East coast time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go into the Settings app.
2. Enter the General pane and select Date & Time.
3. Set your time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings then date and time then
Turn the set automatically switch to off 
Then you can change it ;)